# Finding start value in a column and increment by 1 until the last year

Tags: r, min

I'm trying to find the starting value of the dummy variable and increment it by 1.

Here is a sample data:

```
id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4) 
date = c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014) 
income = c(100,20,45,50,70,45,66,21,45,234,124,5325,645,23234,2352,456,24234,34656,5633,13524) 
participation = c(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1) 
df <- data.frame(id,date,income,participation)
```

To describe this data, I've created a longitudinal data for each person's income and participation in an activity dating from 2010 to 2014. I'm trying to see the participation effect on their income overtime. What I am picturing is the following:

```
id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4) 
date = c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014) 
income = c(100,20,45,50,70,45,66,21,45,234,124,5325,645,23234,2352,456,24234,34656,5633,13524) 
participation = c(0,0,0,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,1,2) 
df <- data.frame(id,date,income,participation)
```

I'm honestly lost because participation value is already a dummy variable. Is there a way to maybe group participation and date together to generate increments? Any idea would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Is the first df the input and the second the output?  If not what is the input and what is the desired output and what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After grouping by 'id', get the `cummax` of 'participation' and then do a cumulative sum on it

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(participation = cumsum(cummax(participation)))
```

Comment: Thank you, but it actually adds up to all ids... was wondering why it would do that?

Comment: @Sun Did you loaded `plyr` package along with `dplyr`.  If that is the case, the `mutate` might be masked from the plyr mutate.  try with `dplyr::mutate(participation = cumsum(cummax(participation)))`